# Comparing two String arrays

Tags: java

I'm making a program that compares two text files and returns their similarity (based on a given algorithm). For each unique word in the first file, I want to find the probabilities that they occur in the second file. But whenever I run my program the similarity returned is always 0.0. This is what I have right now:

```
public static double nestedLoop(String[] doc1, String[] doc2) {
    // nested loop: sort doc1, for each unique word in doc1, find all
    // occurences in doc2 using a sequential search

    java.util.Arrays.sort(doc1);

    double similarity = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < doc1.length - 1; i++) {
        if (doc1[i] != doc1[i + 1]) {
        String unique = doc1[i];
        double count = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < doc2.length; j++) {
                if (unique == doc2[j]) {
                    count++;
                    similarity += count / doc2.length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return similarity;
}
```

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (unique == doc2[j]) {
```

should be

```
if (unique.equals(doc2[j])) {
```

Same for  `if (doc1[i] != doc1[i + 1]) {`

should be:

```
 if (!(doc1[i].equals(doc1[i + 1]))) {
```

`String` comparison should always use `equals()` instead of `==`  (except case of String literal comparison)

Please read [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: WOOOOOW I am stupid. I've definitely run into this before. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: actually, one more small question. If I have to use `equals()` for `String` comparison, how come in the first `if` statement I can use the `!=` to compare `doc1[i]` and `doc[i + 1]`? Aren't they also `String`s?

Comment: @59eagle: Valid question, yes you need to use .equals() there also.

Comment: @ColinD: Added clarification.